# Generating a few layers from 3D laser scanner

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to generate several layers of points that I obtain from 3D laser scanner. Will it be possible to do this without building 3D point clouds?

Any suggestion how to go about this.

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10514/generating-a-few-layers-from-3d-laser-scanner/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-07-18**:
Yes, you got it right. Thanks..@ Martin Günter, i think you had better copy and paste your answer in the box below, so I can tick your answer as "right" or at least the one that I was hunting..

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-07-17**:
What do you mean by "several layers of points"? Do you mean all points recorded by the 3D laser scanner lying on several 2D planes that are horizontal to the ground? You could do that without explicitly building 3D point clouds, using trigonometry, but why? I think point clouds would be easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean by "several layers of points"? Do you mean all points recorded by the 3D laser scanner lying on several 2D planes that are horizontal to the ground? You could do that without explicitly building 3D point clouds, using trigonometry, but why? I think point clouds would be easiest.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0